# facebook user location, birthday in node.js | Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

Unable to get `location` `hometown` and `birthday` of user (with access_token) in node.js though It works in **Browser** and [**Graph API Explorer**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation%2Cage_range%2Cemail%2Cbirthday%2Cbio%2Cabout%2Chometown%2Cgender&version=v2.5).

EDIT: I am using [Passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) to get `access_token` with following `scopes` :

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ["email", "user_location", "user_hometown", "user_birthday"] }));

profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name', 'birthday', 'gender', 'location', 'hometown', 'locale', 'age_range']
```

Browser Url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,location,age_range,email,birthday,hometown,gender&access_token=Access_Token_Here
```

Response:

```
{
   "id": "7766..........",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "location": {
      "id": "11..........",
      "name": "Berlin, Germany"
   },
   "age_range": {
      "min": 21
   },
   "email": "john@doe.com",
   "birthday": "09/09/1999",
   "hometown": {
      "id": "10...............",
      "name": "Green Town"
   },
   "gender": "any"
}
```

Node.js Try 1:

```
var graph = require("fbgraph");

graph.setAccessToken("token_here");

graph.get("me?fields=gender,name,age_range,email,picture,birthday,about,bio,hometown", function(err, res) {
  if(err)
      console.log("err ", err);
  else
      console.log("res ",res); // data here 
});
```

Node.js Try 2:

```
var request = require('request');

request("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,location,age_range,email,birthday,hometown,gender&access_token=" + token,function(err, resp, body){
                                if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
                                    console.log(body);
                                }
                            });
```

Response in Node.js for both tries:

```
{
   "id": "7766..........",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "age_range": {
      "min": 21
   },
   "email": "john@doe.com",
   "gender": "any"
}
//location, hometown, birthday are not coming here
```

Comment: ...and you are using the exact same access token and the exact same app in the api explorer?

Comment: @luschn access_token is retrieved using `passport.js` with all scopes provided, and api is same while using with `request.js`

Comment: Did you use the same access token for your test in GAE? Debug your access token, to check whether it really includes the permissions you think it does.

Comment: @CBroe I have updated post, I am using `passport-facebook` for getting access token and providing proper scopes

Comment: Great. And now try and answer my question, please.

Comment: @CBroe you point seems right, the token given by `passport` when used in browser not works, It means it has no permissions. But as you can see in post I am providing proper scopes to `passport.authenticate` and `profileFields` then why its not right access token with permissions?

Comment: Remove the app from your settings (via the facebook.com UI), and then try and login to it again. Do you get asked for all the permissions you specified then?

Comment: "this-node-app will receive the following info: your public profile and email address." This is all I see, what I am doing wrong? How to fix?